# 9-Year-Old Kenmore Auto Dry Not Working

Tags: dryer

Kenmore Model 61402 electric clothes dryer is not turning off automatically. When the knob is set to "Normal" auto dry, it runs indefinitely even when the clothes are hot and dry. This just started happening in the past month or three. I am not the primary user of this appliance, but I do know it was working properly until now.

Is it possible to troubleshoot and repair?

Does this model have a thermostat or a hidden moisture sensor that could cause the problem?

Comment: It sounds like maybe a sensor.  Will need to find the cost of the sensor plus the cost to install it/inspect for the right problem to see if repair or replace is the right option.  Might only take a phone call to a repair place to find out a range of cost to repair.

Comment: @crip659 That's true and I'm trying to gather more info first.  Going to try the Air Dry cycle to see if the whole timer knob is even moving anymore.

Comment: How old is it? As a responsible person, I always want to fix something rather than throw it out, waste not, want not.  But the last couple of appliance repairs were so expensive that it didn't make sense. Hate to say it, but these days if you get 10-12 years out of a major appliance, you're doing good.   Even if you are handy and can fix things yourself, the parts can be very expensive.   In your case, like Crip said, it might be just a sensor, but I suspect it's the timer, which would be costly to replace.  EDIT:  Crap:  Just reread the title of your post. 9yo, maybe time to replace.

Comment: "Is it possible to troubleshoot" yes, most likely, "and repair?" yes, if parts are available. "is replacement the cheaper option?" nobody knows until they know how much parts will cost.

Comment: That model does have moisture sensor Guessing it is the Part Number: WP3387223 cost $6

Comment: So far determined the timer costs about $180 and the current model, to get a whole new dryer, is about $419 with delivery and haulaway.  Still trying to learn if @Ruskes is correct about the presence of a moisture sensor somewhere behind the bulkhead, or is there a thermostat that might be worth replacing as a cheaper troubleshooting step.

Comment: Youtube or a search might give an idea on the work involved.  Might just be a few screws to undo and a couple of wires to disconnect.  A 6 buck sensor is well within repair region.  180 is almost at the high range for repair.

Comment: @crip659 I will keep looking and if you have any suggestions to improve my question feel free to edit.  Seems like the majority of comments were helpful so far.

Comment: @Ruskes I was unable to find anything about a Moisture Bar in my Kenmore 61402.  I'm leaning away from that idea now.

Comment: @crip659 I did find a video about testing the thermostat by simply looking at the heater box from behind and seeing if it ever turns off after the exhaust gets hot.  If it's as simple as that, then I would have a solution.  Testing next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Troubleshooting**

This problem might be caused by a thermostat failed closed.  Because the thermostat is supposed to be closed at room temperature, there is no simple electrical test.

I'm borrowing from a [video by The Appliancepreneur](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDt3-1wFnLQ).

- Empty out the clothes from the dryer.
- Turn off the lights.
- Start the dryer in auto mode.
- Stand behind the dryer and look for a faint glow from the heater box grille.
- After a few minutes, the heater should turn off.
- After that, the heater should short cycle.

**If the heater is always on**

The thermostat for this model is roughly $30 and available from easy-to-find websites.

To DIY: The thermostat is located between the blower and the exhaust pipe.  It will be necessary to remove the back cover.  There's a diagram and basic info at [ApplianceRepair.net](https://www.appliancerepair.net/clothes-dryer-repair-3.html)

**If the thermostat is working as expected**

This model doesn't have a moisture sensor, so the most likely problem is in the timer.  The timer for this model is roughly $180.

A new Kenmore dryer with delivery and haulaway starts around $530.